# Linking to another page from a google maps marker

Tags: c#, google-maps

I am coding in c# and using the Artem.Google v6 package to create my map on my website. I am trying to create links from the markers that are dropped onto the map, all of the markers need to link to the same page but with a different ID. strID contains the entire address that each marker needs to link to. This is how I create the marker:

```
Marker m = new Marker() { Address = strAddress, Info = strName, Animation = MarkerAnimation.Drop };
m.Info = ConvertStringToLink(strID);
GoogleMap1.Markers.Add(m);
```

I made this method to try and change the marker's Info into a link:

```
private string ConvertStringToLink(string msg)
        {
            string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
            Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return r.Replace(msg, "<a href=\"$1\" title=\"Click to open in a new window or tab\" target=\"&#95;blank\">$1</a>").Replace("href=\"www", "href=\"http://www");
        }
```

So that doesn't change the text in the info popup to a link. Am I on the right track here or do I need to do it another way?

Comment: So are you trying to programmatically set the infowindow of each marker so that when you click on each one, it provides a link that allows you to navigate to some other website? Can you provide an example that demonstrates your issue? I'd recommend looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14203291/4241842) answer to start out.

Answer (score 0):

So to get it to work I just formatted the info of the marker to turn it into a link.

```
strName = String.Format("<a href=\"{1}\">{0}</a>", strName, strID);
Marker m = new Marker() { Address = strAddress, Info = strName, Animation = MarkerAnimation.Drop };
```